a dependent claim that further limits the score of an element introduced in the preamble of the independent claim
claim 1:
a computer-implemented method for awarding winners, the winners determined by an algorithm, comprising:

dependent claim 2:
the method of claim 1, wherein the algorithm uses a minimum threshold of 10 points.

The independent claim, claim 1, uses the broadest algorithm possible.
The dependent claim of claim 1, claim 2, limits the scope the algorithm.
The algorithm element is introduced in the preamble of the method.
questions:

Is claim 2 a valid dependent claim of claim 1?


You may want to give this a read: https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/Claim-Interpretation-Preambles-Final-02-18.pdf . It seems like having claim 2 like that forces the bit in the preamble to be a limitation, which is bad.

but the dependent claim is meant to limit the algorithm

_Bear: Yes I understand what you're trying to do, I just don't see a way to do it.

So you are saying that the dependent claim the way I worded it is invalid?

_Bear: Hard to tell as it's a very unconventional way to do things. But it will almost certainly result in the preamble bit being treated as a limitation and thereby requiring an underlying algorithm to be linked in the specification.

@bhuff36 what about the independent claim? Would that require a specific algorithm to be link? The goal of introducing the "an algorithm" in the preamble is so that it doesn't have to be any specific algorithm.

Note that the word algorithm itself makes people jump to the idea that it is abstract and therefore not patentable subject matter.

is there another word that I can substitute for "algorithm"

For example, what if I use "process" or "method" instead of "algorithm"?

Much better to use those words
